# PHP null coalescing operator confusion - how to use in an if statement?

Tags: php

I usually do this in PHP to handle post parameters...

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {

    echo 'This is the post section';
    echo 'Output Attributes';
    echo $attribute1
    echo $attribute2

} else {

    echo 'The post is empty';

}
```

In an attempt to simplyfy things I am trying to use the null coalescing operator but I am slightly confused. uising an exmample I have this..

```
$name = $_POST['name'] ?? 'The post is empty';
```

But how do I get this to act like an `if` statement so I can output different sections for example?

Comment: Perhaps you'd be better with a ternary operator e.g.  `$name = (isset($_POST['name']) ? "Something" : "The post is empty");`. Not sure, you didn't specify what the output should be.

Comment: You don't. The null operator is designed to replace a simple construct like `$name = isset($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : "default";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
$name = $_POST['name'] ?? 'The post is empty';
```

is equivalent to this:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
  $name = $_POST['name'];
}else{
  $name = 'The post is empty';
}
```

If you want to do anything more complicated than that, you have to go with your own `if/else` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends. One way would be:

```
<?php if ( $_POST['name'] ?? false ) {  } else {} ?>
```

The operator is cool, but it can't do everything. And here it doesn't make it better.